# Checking for null values in a mapped row using java8

Tags: java, java-8

I use model classes to map Tables and then show the data using a XML/JSON schema (Objects generated through xjc).

One thing i do not like to do while binding values from table to XML doc is null checks. Suppose there are 40 columns out of which 35 can be null.

What i am doing is very simple like below;

```
if (dataFromTable.getUserPhoneNumber != null) {
    jaxbObject.setUserPhoneNumber(dataFromTable.getUserPhoneNumber);
}
```

Is it possible i can make 1 method which can filter all nulls and set them to `jaxbObjects` without writing code like above for each and every column?

As i see Java 8 has `filter()` which can filter nulls from a collection. But what if i want to apply this to a Single Object(1 Row from table) and check each column values for null?

Comment: I normally use the entity framework for this then you can just make a class an entity and read back the data from the database.

Comment: @Rajkishan. The `Stream` API can only work on `Collections` or an array converted to a stream. That said, take a look at `Stream.of` method.

Comment: @CKing : Is there anyother way i can do this null check but dont have to write so many `if`...?

Comment: @Rajkishan Don't have Java-8 on this machine. You can take a look at `Stream.of` method. And yes, it can also be done without streams by using Functional interfaces and lambdas. Not on a java-8 machine to try it out.

Comment: Without `if`: `Optional.ofNullable(dataFromTable.getUserPhoneNumber()) .ifPresent(jaxbObject::setUserPhoneNumber)`. Without repeating it for every property: use a framework

Comment: @Holger : Just how i wanted. Thank you. Can you post it so i can accept as answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to handle the possibility of a value being `null` without an explicit `if` statement, you can use `Optional`:

```
Optional.ofNullable(dataFromTable.getUserPhoneNumber())
        .ifPresent(jaxbObject::setUserPhoneNumber);
```

It’s not such a big win compared to an ordinary `if` statement. `Optional`s will show their advantages when being returned by a method instead of a nullable reference in the first place and/or when combining it with multiple processing steps.

Still, it has the advantage of calling `getUserPhoneNumber()` only a single time while not requiring an additional local variable.